# Codeigniter, Ajax, delete staff according to their id not working

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter-3

I am designing a page where the user will click on a delete link a modal should appear confirming the deletion. but when I click on the confirm button on the modal nothing happens.

here is my code:

**view page:**

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="removeTeacherModal">

<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Remove Teacher</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div id="remove-messages"></div>
      <p>Do you really want to remove ?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="removeTeacherBtn">confirm</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

**controller  page:**

```
  $button ='
<div class="dropdown text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button"     id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-    expanded="false">
            Action
     </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data- target="#updateTeacherModal"  onClick="editTeacher('.$value['staff_id'].')">Edit</a></li>

          <li><a class="dropdown-item" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data- target="#removeTeacherModal"  onClick="removeTeacher('.$value['staff_id'].')">Remove</a></li>

        </div> ';
```

the above part is a property that will be added dynamically on the page afterwards

this function also is included in the controller page

```
public function removeT($teacherId = null){
        $validator= array('success' => FALSE , 'messages' => array());
        if($teacherId){
            $remove= $this->model_staff->remove($teacherID);
            if($remove){

                $validator['success']=true;
                $validator['messages']='Teacher is removed Successfully';
            }
            else{
                $validator['success']=false;
                $validator['messages']='Error while removing the information';    
            }  
        }
        echo json_encode($validator); 
    }
```

**Model:**

```
public function remove($teacherId = null){
    if($teacherId){
        $this->db->where('staff_id', $teacherId);
        $result = $this->db->delete('staff');
        return ($result == true) ? true : false;
    }   
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
    function removeTeacher(teacherId = null){

      if(teacherId){

         $('#removeTeacherBtn').unbind('click').bind('click', function() {

            $.ajax({
            url: base_url + 'staff/removeT/'+teacherId ,
            type:'post',
            dataType :'json' ,
            success: function(response){
                if (response.success == true){
                   $('#messages').html('<div class="alert alert-success  alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">'+
      '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria- label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+  response.messages +
    '</div>');
                manageTeacherTable.ajax.reload(null,false);
                $('#removeTeacherModal').modal('hide');

                }

                else {
                    $('#remove-messages').html('<div class="alert alert-  warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">'+
     '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-   label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+    response.messages +
   '</div>');     
                }
               }    
            });
       });     
      }
  }
```

Comment: bind/unbind are deprecated and were superseded way back in jQuery 1.7 by off and on - check the docs. They'll still work for now, but eventually they won't. And the new methods have improved behaviour, too.

Comment: Anyway, as to your actual question....you say "nothing happens"...but it seems unlikely. From what you've shown, on the surface it looks ok as written. So..do you understand how you use your browser's Developer Tools to debug your code? Check the Console for errors, and check the Network tab to see what is happening to your AJAX request - it could be failing silently for some reason, but the tools will give you details like the response status code and any response data from the server. If needed you can also step through your code with the debugger line by line to see what code is being run.

Comment: I changed it now to on and off but nothing happened. the thing is that no errors in the console and I can't get to know from which part it is not working

Comment: In that case do the rest of the debugging I've written about above. In particular to track what is happening to the ajax request.

Comment: The only other thing I would change in your code right now is on the confirm button, change `<button type="submit"` to `<button type="button"` - you don't need it to submit the traditional way because you're using AJAX, so let's remove that possibility, in case it's trying to do that.

Comment: One more thing actually, you've written code to add a success message to `$('#messages')` but I can't see any `<div id="messages">` in your code, so maybe it simply isn't writing the message to anywhere valid. But before we get to that you need to check if the ajax call is succeeding, or not.

Comment: Many thanks to your answer, I was stuck in this error for one day although I have done that before but since I can't see any error in the console but after your answer I checked the network and found that I wrote Teacher ID instead of TeacherId .... again many thanks

Comment: yes Thanks again you are really helpful , I wasn't able to see anything in the network but after opening the header I found the problem